# Arrange some observations in dataframe by one column, and others by another

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
dat<- data.frame(question=c("Question 1", "Question 3", "Question 2", 
                      "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 1"),
           answer=c("Answer 1", "Answer 1", "1- Yes", "No",
                    "Answer 2", "Answer 2"),
           total=c(40,70,20,80,30,60))
dat

#    question   answer total
# 1 Question 1 Answer 1    40
# 2 Question 3 Answer 1    70
# 3 Question 2   1- Yes    20
# 4 Question 2       No    80
# 5 Question 3 Answer 2    30
# 6 Question 1 Answer 2    60
```

I want to arrage the dataframe according to the order of the variable `question` , and by either the variable `answer` or `total`, depending on the value of `question`. If `question == "Question 1"` or `question == "Question 3"`, I would like to arrange by `total`, and if `question == "Question 2"` I would like to arrange by `answer`. This is the output I want to achieve:

```
#     question   answer total
# 1 Question 1 Answer 2    60
# 2 Question 1 Answer 1    40
# 3 Question 2   1- Yes    20
# 4 Question 2       No    80
# 5 Question 3 Answer 1    70
# 6 Question 3 Answer 2    30
```

How can I achieve this? Ideally, I would like a solution using Dplyr's `arrange()`. I have tried by combining `arrange()` and `ifelse()` but have not gotten the results I want. This is what I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% arrange(question, ifelse(question=="Question 2", answer, desc(total)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrange with case_when ought to do the job:

```r
dat %>% arrange(
            question,
            case_when(
                question %in% c("Qustion 1","Question 3") ~ as.double(desc(total)),
                question == "Question 2" ~ as.double(xtfrm(answer))
            )
        )
```

Now I've somewhat baffled by why as.double *is needed* there, but it complains otherwise, and seems to do the right thing with it there.

Btw, you'r approach works with `as.double` too:

```r
dat %>% arrange(question, if_else(question=="Question 2", as.double(xtfrm(answer)), as.double(desc(total))))
```

(but will be limited to handle two columns unless you nest multiple if_else's (dplyr::if_else is preferable to base::ifelse ))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.by_group` argument of `arrange()`

```
    dat %>% 
        group_by(question) %>% 
        arrange(.by_group = T, desc(ifelse(question == "Question 2", answer, total)) )
        %>% ungroup()
```